# Can two Apps (owner and client) share same database with different authentication spaces?

Tags: android, firebase, web, flutter

I need two apps to work with client and its owner. I need to take access of their database mutually. I mean client need to fetch some data about owner and vice versa.

I think they should have different authentication spaces(just like different folders for owner and clients).So that if one phone No. is registered as owner and same is registered with client then their is no cross linking or confusion in the authentication hub between client and owner.

I am using Firebase as backend. How can it be achieved with it or is their some other approach for this kind of problem.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is to create private documents (either using cloud functions or from some server) describing the roles of each user based on their authentication ID. Then you can use Firebase Security Rules to determine which data can be accessed by whom, and whether they can edit them or not.

This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eW5MdE3ZcAw) from firebase channel does explain a similar scenario and it's generally about the security rules of Firestore.